# ajax load data from php page and mysqli

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, load

I have a database that contains information for `x` variable. I want to have php page that load datafrom mysqli with ajax and my phpapi page. so 
I create my database and it fills up every 1 minute.
I create a php page that load a data from mysqli and output with 
this is my php page that load data from my mysqli and it working right

this is `myphpapi.php` page

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("x.x.x.x","boob","booob");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"sss");
$sql = "SELECT `x` FROM ddd order by id desc limit 1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$output = json_encode($result);
echo $output;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

this part work well but  I have another php page that contain ajax. When I push button, nothing happend

please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ajax test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    this is ajax test
</h1>
<div id="main">

</div>
<button type="button" id="ajax_button">click me</button>


<script>
    replaceText();
    function replaceText() {
        var target = document.getElementById("main");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'myphpapi.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
                target.innerHTML = 'loading . . . .';
            }
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                target.innerHTML = json;
            }

            xhr.send();

        }
    }
    var button = document.getElementById("ajax_button");
    button.addEventListener("click",replaceText);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? Have you checked the response in the Network tab to see if the JSON is coming back?

Comment: Note that even if this works, it will just display `[Object object]` in the DIV. `JSON.parse()` returns an object, not a string. If you want to display the value of `x`, it should be `target.innerHTML = json.x;`

Comment: your ajax code is messed up - you have the `send` method inside the `readystatechange` handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the order a little within your ajax function and move the `send` method outside the `onreadystatechange` event handler it should work ~ though as pointed ut by @Barmar `JSON.parse` will return an object.

```
function replaceText() {
    var target = document.getElementById("main");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
            target.innerHTML = 'loading . . . .';
        }
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            target.innerHTML = json;
        }
    }

    xhr.open('GET', 'myphpapi.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send();
}
```